# Problem with download files from databases through GridView

Tags: asp.net, forms, web

I have problem with files. I'm trying to download files from databases 
through gridview, but after I download them, they are with wrong name and extensions. Their name are my web form name and their extensions are `.aspx`.

In the database they are saved in the correct format.

Here are my code-behind

```
public partial class data : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DecumentsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            FillData();
        }
    }

    private void FillData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getDecuments", cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            dt.Load(reader);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo filename = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.FileName);
        byte[] documentContent = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
        string name = filename.Name;
        string extnt = filename.Extension;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("savedocument", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", documentContent);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@extn",extnt);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    private void Donwload(int id)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getdocument", cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            dt.Load(reader);
        }
        string name = dt.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
        byte[] document = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["DocumentContent"];
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ContentType = "application/octetstream";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Dispisition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", name));
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Lenght", document.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(document);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
    }
        protected void OpenDocument(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender;
            GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)lnk.NamingContainer;
            int id = int.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            Donwload(id);
        }
    }
}
```

and my html

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Document"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Documents">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="OpenDocument" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
    </div>
</form>
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aphm1.png)